# Group Blank Rows?

Tags: sql, group-by

I want to turn this:

Query:

```
select A.DispatchNote, B.MStockCode, B.NComment
from MdnMaster A 
  left join MdnDetail B on A.DispatchNote = B.DispatchNote
```

| A.DispatchNote | B.MStockCode | B.NComment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 258579/0001 | RFK2-8520-150-25 |  |
| 258579/0001 |  | FREIGHT |
| 258579/0001 |  | 1 Parcel UPS Ground 2/28/2020 |
| 258579/0001 |  | Trk#: 1Z8R9V900342021397 -- 0.9 lb |
| 258585/0001 | CAW2-1832-25L |  |
| 258585/0001 |  | FREIGHT |
| 258585/0001 |  | 6 Parcels UPS Ground 2/28/2020 |
| 258585/0001 |  | Trk#: 1Z8R9V900342126962 -- 15 lb |
| 258585/0001 |  | Trk#: 1Z8R9V900342515176 -- 15 lb |
| 258585/0001 |  | Trk#: 1Z8R9V900340703781 -- 15 lb |
| 258585/0001 |  | Trk#: 1Z8R9V900340988792 -- 15 lb |
| 258585/0001 |  | Trk#: 1Z8R9V900340706204 -- 15 lb |
| 258585/0001 |  | Trk#: 1Z8R9V900342832014 -- 15 lb |

into this:

Query:

```
select A.DispatchNote, B.MStockCode, B.NComment
from MdnMaster A 
  left join MdnDetail B on A.DispatchNote = B.DispatchNote
where A.Customer = 'LAWSON' -- Not visible here, but the whole query only pulls LAWSON orders
  and B.MLineShipDate >= FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY,-4,getdate()),'yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000') -- This pulls only orders from yesterday's date
```

| A.DispatchNote | B.MStockCode | B.NComment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 258579/0001 | RFK2-8520-150-25 | Trk#: 1Z8R9V900342021397 -- 0.9 lb |
| 258585/0001 | CAW2-1832-25L | Trk#: 1Z8R9V900342126962 -- 15 lb |

But I'm not sure how. When I run my query I get **nothing**, and I think it's because I'm supposed to do something with a group by but I'm not sure.

Basically I want to clear the empty rows in MStockCode (or condense the rows I guess) and only pull the first visible tracking number that shows up for each dispatchnote when I run the query unsorted).

Comment: Why are you formatting the date?  I do hope `B.MLineShipDate` had the DATETIME type ?  then you do not need `DATEFORMAT(.....)`

Comment: I guess I'm formatting it because for some reason I get the exact time when our system has everything set to 0:00:00 for time rather than the exact.

Comment: Please do not guess, Investigate this issue, and solve it.

Answer (score 0):

For the grouping, you can start doing this. it will get less records:

```
select 
   A.DispatchNote, 
   B.MStockCode, 
   B.NComment 
from MdnMaster A 
left join MdnDetail B on A.DispatchNote = B.DispatchNote 
      and (B.NComment LIKE 'Trk%' OR B.MStockCode is not null)
```

Combining them on 1 line:

```
select 
   A.DispatchNote, 
   MAX(B.MStockCode) as StockCode, 
   MAX(B.NComment) as Comment 
from MdnMaster A 
left join MdnDetail B on A.DispatchNote = B.DispatchNote 
      and (B.NComment LIKE 'Trk%' OR B.MStockCode is not null)
group by A.DispatchNote
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a small script in T-SQL so I could run and debug with your data. I added one sample record to verify the behavior when there is no tracking information.

```sql
DECLARE @MdnMaster TABLE (DispatchNote VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
DECLARE @MdnDetail TABLE (DispatchNote VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, MStockCode VARCHAR(50) NULL, NComment VARCHAR(50) NULL);

INSERT INTo @MdnMaster(DispatchNote) VALUES ('258579/0001'),('258579/0001'),('258579/0001'),('258579/0001'),
('258585/0001'),('258585/0001'),('258585/0001'),('258585/0001'),('258585/0001'),('258585/0001'),
('258585/0001'),('258585/0001'),('258585/0001'),('999999/TEST');

INSERT INTO @MdnDetail(DispatchNote, MStockCode, NComment) VALUES 
('258579/0001','RFK2-8520-150-25',NULL)
,('258579/0001',NULL,'FREIGHT')
,('258579/0001',NULL,'1 Parcel UPS Ground 2/28/2020')
,('258579/0001',NULL,'Trk#: 1Z8R9V900342021397 -- 0.9 lb')
,('258585/0001','CAW2-1832-25L',NULL)
,('258585/0001',NULL,'FREIGHT')
,('258585/0001',NULL,'6 Parcels UPS Ground 2/28/2020')
,('258585/0001',NULL,'Trk#: 1Z8R9V900342126962 -- 15 lb')
,('258585/0001',NULL,'Trk#: 1Z8R9V900342515176 -- 15 lb')
,('258585/0001',NULL,'Trk#: 1Z8R9V900340703781 -- 15 lb')
,('258585/0001',NULL,'Trk#: 1Z8R9V900340988792 -- 15 lb')
,('258585/0001',NULL,'Trk#: 1Z8R9V900340706204 -- 15 lb')
,('258585/0001',NULL,'Trk#: 1Z8R9V900342832014 -- 15 lb')
,('999999/TEST','TEST-WITHOUT-TRACKING','No tracking');

SELECT 
   m.DispatchNote, 
   MAX(d.MStockCode) as StockCode, 
   MAX(case when d.NComment like 'Trk%' then d.NComment end) as NComment
FROM @MdnMaster AS m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @MdnDetail AS d on m.DispatchNote = d.DispatchNote 
      AND (d.NComment LIKE 'Trk%' OR d.MStockCode is not null)
GROUP BY m.DispatchNote
```

This is the output:

| DispatchNote | StockCode | NComment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 258579/0001 | RFK2-8520-150-25 | Trk#: 1Z8R9V900342021397 -- 0.9 lb |
| 258585/0001 | CAW2-1832-25L | Trk#: 1Z8R9V900342832014 -- 15 lb |
| 999999/TEST | TEST-WITHOUT-TRACKING | NULL |

There are other approaches, but this should work in most RDBMS. For the tables you have, it is simply:

```sql
SELECT 
   m.DispatchNote, 
   MAX(d.MStockCode) as StockCode, 
   MAX(case when d.NComment like 'Trk%' then d.NComment end) as NComment
FROM MdnMaster AS m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN MdnDetail AS d on m.DispatchNote = d.DispatchNote 
      AND (d.NComment LIKE 'Trk%' OR d.MStockCode is not null)
GROUP BY m.DispatchNote
```